# Auto date entry in excel 2010

Tags: excel

how to add a auto date entry if we enter any data in a cell?  Eg: if cell A1 has entered a data (either number or text, a date of the entry day should automatically add on cell B1, and should repeated A2:B2, A3:B3......please help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

add this code:

```
If (Target.Column = 1) Then Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Now
```

Every time you change something in the column "A", column "B" is updated... No check on the previous values are made.

Comment: Thank you marc_s . the code is working fine.